# execute program while window handled mfc

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog

I want to make program work while handle is available. I thinking about setting timer on initialization... and insert all source of program in to it, but if I got lost handle when program processing in while loop it will not let me close dialog box immediately.

```
BOOL WaitProcessDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
   CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();
   SetTimer(IDC_PROGRESS1, 0, NULL);
   return TRUE;
}

void WaitProcessDlg::OnTimer(UINT nIDEvent)
{
   if(::FindWindow(NULL, str)){
   tempHWND = ::FindWindow(NULL, str);
      while(tempHWND){
----------------------->>>>>>>>>>>> A LOT OF CODING <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<----------------------
      }
   EndDialog( 0 );
   KillTimer(IDC_PROGRESS1);
    }

  CDialog::OnTimer(nIDEvent);
}
```

So my question is what the best way to close dialog when handle of external application may lost, maybe insert thread or there are any other way to do that?

Comment: Your question is not very clear - can you show some code and some examples of the problem your seeing?

Comment: Handle of WHAT program? Is it some external application?

Comment: Yes, handle of external application.

Comment: So are available any idea?

Comment: Question: Are you trying to execute another process (i.e. a separate executable) and then waiting for it to finish?

Comment: Yes... but I will not just wait, but send events to external application and I want make like security because external app can crash... so when I lost my handle I want to stop my program and close my dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need a windows hook.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959(v=vs.85).aspx#whgetmessagehook

with WH_GETMESSAGE you get to see the windows events being processed by the other application's window, you could then wait for the WM_CLOSE to show up, and kill your dialog.